# Keep aspect ratio of div when resizing window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue which is a little hard to explain. I have a div which has a 2:1 aspect ratio. And I want it to have a 100% width or height based on the browsers window size.

If the window height is greater than the divs height the the size should be based on 100% width.

And if window height is less than the divs height the size should be based on 100% height.

With my curren approach it is flashing when I size larger.

Look at this link http://acozmo.com/me/ for a demo.

HTML

```
<section id="container">
</section>
```

JQuery

```
function update() {

        var $documentHeight = $(document).height();
        var $windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var $documentWidth = $(document).width();
        var $windowWidth = $(window).width();

        var $container = $('#container');

        if ( $windowHeight >= $documentHeight ) {
            $container.width($windowWidth);
            $container.height($windowWidth / 2);
        }
        if ( $windowHeight < $documentHeight ) {
            $container.width($windowHeight * 2);
            $container.height($windowHeight);
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        update()
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        update();
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resize to fit inside the window while maintaining aspect ratio, set up your container with an initial size and then divide the area width by the container's width to get the scale. You then need a check to make sure that scale doesn't make the height too great. See code below and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yUenJ/) - I've added the case where the height is greater than the width too for completeness.

To stop the flashing, throttle your resize function using setTimeout. This will ensure that update is only called once every n milliseconds. You can play with the number until you find the right balance.

```
var container = $('#container'),
    updateTimeout,
    threshold = 100;

function update() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
        windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        width = container.width(),
        height = container.height(),
        scale;

    if ( windowWidth > windowHeight ) {
        scale = windowWidth / width;
        if ( height * scale > windowHeight ) {
            scale = windowHeight / height;
        }
    }
    else {
        scale = windowHeight / height;
        if ( width * scale > windowWidth ) {
            scale = windowWidth / width;
        }
    }
    container.width(Math.round(width * scale));
    container.height(Math.round(height * scale));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    update();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(updateTimeout);
    updateTimeout = setTimeout(update, threshold);
});
```

Comment: That did stop the flashing. But sometimes its 100% where it should not

Comment: Do you want to contain the div within the window while maintaining the aspect ratio?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some resize code. Hope it does the job for you!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably happening because the fact that you are using a second `if`, instead of an `else` . . . it hits the first `if`, shrinks the height, and then hits the second `if` and increases it.

Try changing this (the second `if`):

```
if ( $windowHeight < $documentHeight ) {
```

. . . to this:

```
else {
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help

Comment: Hmmm . . . okay, well you should still keep that change in . . . it would have caused you issues at some point.   :D  Also, on a side note, it doesn't look like you ever use the `$documentWidth` variable.